# Best coding practice for large, state-based arduino projects.

Tags: c, arduino

I come form a PC/C# background and I've noticed that as the complexity of my arduino projects become larger, they become messy and they lack an overall template.

My C# projects are always very rigidly structured but because C is not OOP, I'm struggling to apply the same principles. For example, I want to set a bunch of lights to flash for a certain amount of time and then turn off. This would be easy in C#, but all the solutions in C I've seen involve a mess of checking timers each time through a loop.

So my specific question is, are there any established C programming practices for this, and if not, what would be a good resource to learn this sort of thing?

Comment: C is as OO as you make it. large projects like "The Gimp" are written with an OO design in C.  The arduino language "Processing" is a superset of C++.

Comment: Best practice: don't use Arduino for larger and/or professional projects; it's a bloody hobbyist platform. As for C# vs C, it's because in C# you write "someone else do the actual work for me please" while in C you do the actual work. That has nothing to do with OOP, it is merely high-level versus low-level.

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions.

*1) Regarding the coding structure*

If you're working on bare-metal designs, the simplest [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) is [State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Sometimes the project complexity is too big for that, then you should look into [RTOS](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library).

Even if Arduinos are AVR based, I recommend to look into the ARM CMSIS library code. For me, the way it handles the memory map with structs was enlightening.

*2) Regarding Blinking Leds.*

If you're using while loops, and this wasn't your first project, you're probably doing it wrong. You should look into [hardware interrupts](https://www.robotshop.com/letsmakerobots/arduino-101-timers-and-interrupts).

Comment: 1. I've looked into finite state machines, but my understanding is that they tend to not be great when you have lots of independent states changing all the time. I'll do some research on it. 

2. Unfortunately, its not my code. The current implementation was a bit gross for me so I'm keen for a more elegant solution.

Comment: if you have lots of independant states create several state machines and run them one after another.

Comment: @pseudoabdul   .. which is why a typical state-machine that handles many different events and has very complex state, (e. a Windows/C# GUI), serializes all  events into messages and queues them to just one thread that runs the state machine.  This is relatively easy to do when you have a 'real' multitasking OS kernel, as is the implementation of timers that fire timeout events into the state machine.  A xvan suggests, such systems are entirely dependent upon interrupts.